# Cannot login after changing password in Kubuntu via System Settings

Tags: 12.04, kubuntu, password

I just changed my password in Kubuntu 12.04, via the Systems Settings dialog. After this I was able to "sudo su" and work on some other unrelated tasks. After restarting the computer, I can no longer login as the user whose password was changed. Any help, and/or redirection to a bug report on this will be greatly appreciated. I have a lot of files, and work and such on this user's account, and would hate to lose normal access to it. In the mean time, I will not be changing passwords on user's until I know the current hazards, caveats.

Thank You,

John